# How to convert an UTF String to ANSI and Create an ANSI text file in ExternalSD with JAVA-ANDROID

Tags: java, android, utf-8, cp1252

I wrote a android app in java to get user answers and save them in a file.
The problem is that this file is saved in utf-8.
The end user will open these files in the IBM SPSS, an application for windows that can read files only in ANSI (windows-1252).

**How do I create files in ANSI code to save in a SD card from java-android app?**

I think I know that to convert Strings to ANSI I should use:

```
String unicode = new String(asciiBytes, "windows-1252");
```

**Is that correct?**

My code to save the file is this:

```
File interviewFile = new File(placeOfSDD, fileName);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(interviewFile, true);
writer.append(textBody);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

"textBody" is the String to convert to ANSI, and the "interviewFile" is the file to be saved as ANSI too.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strings are represented within the JVM as Unicode.  When you write it out, you need to convert it to an appropriate character set.

To do this, use an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and specify the `Charset`.

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true), 
                                                   "windows-1252");
writer.append(textBody);
writer.close();
```

---

Regarding your first question:

> I think I know that to convert Strings to ANSI I should use:
>   `String unicode = new String(asciiBytes, "windows-1252");` 
>   Is that correct?

Given an array of bytes representing characters in the 'windows-1252' character set, this code will construct you the appropriate Java String (internally represented as Unicode within the JVM).  This *isn't* "converting Strings to ANSI" ... it's doing the opposite: converting 'windows-1252' to Unicode.

Comment: Is there an easy way to specify what to do with the characters that cannot be represented in CP1252?

Comment: @sarnold: If you want more control of the encoding process, you're meant to use a [CharsetEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html), but I never have.

Comment: Very short answer, but sharp! Thanks!! That solved the case!
I use that because my OS is in Portuguese (Brazil) language.